# If $\sum a_n$ converges and $(b_n)$ converges, then does $\sum a_nb_n$ converge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Is this statement true or false?

If $\sum a_n$ converges and $(b_n)$ converges, then $\sum a_nb_n$ converges.

If true, how do I prove it?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown : I don't think that sort of comparison test works if $\sum_n a_n$ is conditionally convergent.

Comment: Note that convergence implies boundedness!

Comment: @MichaelHardy please see the original version in the revision history.

Comment: @MichaelHardy : My original post erroneously included the word "absolutely" after the first "converges." I understand that his solution is valid in that case. I updated the post to reflect my real question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

$$a_n=b_n=\dfrac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}$$

Answer (score 2):

You may choose $a_n = b_n = (-1)^n * \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$

The series separately converge (easily verifyable with Leibnitz Criterion), however since $a_n b_n = \frac{1}{n} $, the harmonic $\sum \frac{1}{n}$ series commonly known diverges, thus the statement above is not true for all sequences.